# Would it be haram in the eyes of Islam to wear hijab and share pictures on social media with full veil?

Tags: halal-haram, women, hijab, social-media

I want to know more about Islam. It's necessary to know where we can upload pictures and where we are forbidden by Islam. This question is one of my unknown facts. Thank you.

Comment: Islam does not allow taking pictures or drawing of any inanimate object. https://islamqa.org/hanafi/muftionline/106415

Answer (score 0):

It is permissible if images are not abused or provocative or corrupting to the woman. But they should pay attention to this point, so as not to be seen in the eyes of others, even among women; Or attract the attention of non-mahrams, which is not permissible in either case. But if this is not the case and their hijab is normal and others are attracted to this hijab, there is definitely no problem.

https://www.tasnimnews.com/fa/news/1395/04/21/1127414